Can a dart interface be extended outside its own library?
interface class Vehicle {
  int current_state = 0;

  void moveForward(int meters) {
    // ...
  }
}

// Can be constructed.
Vehicle myVehicle = Vehicle();

// ERROR: Can't be inherited.
class Car extends Vehicle {
  int current_state = 12;

  int passengers = 4;
  // ...

  @override
  moveForward(int meters) {
    current_state = current_state + meters;
  }
}

// Can be implemented.
class MockVehicle implements Vehicle {
  int current_state = 0;

  @override
  void moveForward(int meters) {
    // ...
  }
}

void main() {
  Car ACar = new Car();

  ACar.moveForward(5);

  print(ACar.current_state);
}

I saw in the dart official document that:

To define an interface, use the interface modifier. Libraries outside of the interface's own defining library can implement the interface, but not extend it.

but the code above works......
What is happening? It shouldn't work. Can anyone tell me why this works?
https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers
I expected an error but it works...

"but the code above works......" - what should NOT work in your opinion?

@pskink sorry, I misunderstood. i didn't understaned the word "Libraries outside of the interface's own defining library" in https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#interface

Hello! You can answer your own question, as it sounds like you've found the answer.

yes indeed: a dart and b.dart are different libraries
